# Error in updating database row in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

- items: `id, userid, item_name, item_description`

I want to update a row and used the following sql statement for it.

```
$updateQuery = "UPDATE items SET item_name = '$item_name',
item_desc = '$item_desc' WHERE userid = '$userid' 
AND item_name = '$old_name'";
```

But it fails. Is it because I used the `item_name` field, which is to be updated, for selecting the row?

Comment: It must be simething else. Please show the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I see the problem

```
item_desc = '$item_desc'
```

"4 columns id, userid, item_name, **item_description.**"

Change your query to

```
$updateQuery = "UPDATE items SET item_name = '$item_name', item_description = '$item_desc' WHERE userid = '$userid' AND item_name = '$old_name'";
```

Answer (score 2):

you not update item_name because you used it in where clause
or
you can echo this string and run in database terminal to verify.

Try :

```
$updateQuery = "UPDATE items SET item_name = '" . $item_name . "', item_desc = '" . $item_desc . "' WHERE userid = " . $userid . " AND item_name = '" . $old_name . "';"
```

Answer (score 2):

Please notice, in your query, you are referring the last column as "item_desc" which does not exist, as the actual column name is "item_description" .

MySQL is treating "item_desc" as a separate column in your table, but unable to find it, and hence the error.

Also, it is a good idea to pay attention to how you are concatenating your variable to your query. After equal to(=) sign, always use this notation ' ".$variable_name." ' to concatenate. Example:

select column1, column2 from table1 where (column1 = ' ".$variable_name." ' && column2 = ' ".$variable_name." ') ";

Answer (score 1):

You have to concatenate the strings.

```
$updateQuery = "UPDATE items SET item_name = '" . $item_name . "', item_desc = '" . $item_desc . "' WHERE userid = " . $userid . " AND item_name = '" . $old_name . "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `item_desc`, it should be `item_description`.